# How to prevent input fields from duplication?

Tags: javascript, html, input-field

When uploading any file, it's appearing all input fields as the same value even appearing the clear and change button. Also if click the clear button, it's cleared all fields.

How it works each field uniquely?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sanjida96xq2/5gLqthrj/12/

[View Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BtGJ.png)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#close-preview', function(){ 
    $('.image-preview').popover('hide');
   
    $('.image-preview').hover(
        function () {
           $('.image-preview').popover('show');
        }, 
         function () {
           $('.image-preview').popover('hide');
        }
    );    
});

$(function() {
   
    var closebtn = $('<button/>', {
        type:"button",
        text: 'x',
        id: 'close-preview',
        style: 'font-size: initial;',
    });
    closebtn.attr("class","close pull-right");
   
    $('.image-preview').popover({
        trigger:'manual',
        html:true,
        title: "<strong>Preview</strong>"+$(closebtn)[0].outerHTML,
        content: "There's no image",
        placement:'bottom'
    });
    
    $('.image-preview-clear').click(function(){
        $('.image-preview').attr("data-content","").popover('hide');
        $('.image-preview-filename').val("");
        $('.image-preview-clear').hide();
        $('.image-preview-input input:file').val("");
        $(".image-preview-input-title").text("Browse"); 
    }); 
  
    $(".image-preview-input input:file").change(function (){     
        var img = $('<img/>', {
            id: 'dynamic',
            width:250,
            height:200
        });      
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(".image-preview-input-title").text("Change");
            $(".image-preview-clear").show();
            $(".image-preview-filename").val(file.name);            
            img.attr('src', e.target.result);
            $(".image-preview").attr("data-content",$(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
        }        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });  
});



.container{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.image-preview-input {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;    
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;    
}
.image-preview-input input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.image-preview-input-title {
    margin-left:2px;
}



<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">  
            <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> 
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group image-preview [TO HERE]--> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



   

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">  
            <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/> 
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">  
            <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> 
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                   
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/> <!-- rename it -->
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! You should describe in more detail what it is you're experiencing, what it is that you are expecting, and what you have tried so far to solve the problem. StackOverflow aims to keep a high quality Q&A database. For that reason, questions must be as specific and as clear as possible.

Comment: Hi, i am sorry, something wrong inline snippet, but i just added the fiddle now. I am expecting that each input file will work dynamically..

Comment: No worries :) I was not referring to that. The philosophy here is more to have "to the point" questions. As-is, someone will not be able to tell where the problem is and would have to go through the code and guess. I mean, name one or two fields, one or two of the methods you suspect. A bit more insight on the code, to help people understand it faster than reading it by themselves.

Comment: The fiddle is nice, but in time (for future SO users) it might not be available anymore. I am no JavaScript expert, I am just trying to help you form a better question according to the SO philosophy in order to get a good answer

Comment: @Alexandru Clonțea, the input file fields are working fine but when the fields is more than 1, its appearing all fields are same behavior and not working dramatically or uniquely. i hope more explained.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your JS fiddle example here -

https://jsfiddle.net/5gLqthrj/27/

So what had to be updated?

All your code showing the popover, updating the file, etc, used generic `$('.image-preview')` jQuery selector code. However, all 3 file uploaders used that class, so whenever you used that code, all THREE would get selected and updated. You need to be more specific and only select the one clicked, of course.

So how to do that?

There are different ways but here's a simple solution:

When an event (like `click`, or `hover`, both of which you are using) is bound in jQuery, you can reference `$(this)` (or `$(event.currentTarget)`) to figure out exactly WHICH element was clicked. Then, instead of updating *all* elements with that class, you only update `this`. You also have a few other selectors that needed updating with a similar not-specific-enough selector problem, so instead of doing a wholesale `$('.selector-here')` grab, I changed the code to only search for that selector WITHIN the relevant element using `.find`, e.g. `$(this).find('.selector-here')`

Hopefully this makes sense to you :)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#close-preview', function(){ 
    $('.image-preview').popover('hide');
   
    $('.image-preview').hover(
        function () {
           $(this).popover('show');
        }, 
         function () {
           $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    );    
});

$(function() {
   
    var closebtn = $('<button/>', {
        type:"button",
        text: 'x',
        id: 'close-preview',
        style: 'font-size: initial;',
    });
    closebtn.attr("class","close pull-right");
   
    $('.image-preview').popover({
        trigger:'manual',
        html:true,
        title: "<strong>Preview</strong>"+$(closebtn)[0].outerHTML,
        content: "There's no image",
        placement:'bottom'
    });
    
    $('.image-preview-clear').click(function(){
        var $preview = $(this).closest('.image-preview');
        $preview.attr("data-content","").popover('hide');
        $preview.find('.image-preview-filename').val("");
        $preview.find('.image-preview-clear').hide();
        $preview.find('.image-preview-input input:file').val("");
        $preview.find(".image-preview-input-title").text("Browse"); 
    }); 
  
    $(".image-preview-input input:file").change(function (){     
        var img = $('<img/>', {
            id: 'dynamic',
            width:250,
            height:200
        });      
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var $preview = $(this).closest('.image-preview');
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $preview.find(".image-preview-input-title").text("Change");
            $preview.find(".image-preview-clear").show();
            $preview.find(".image-preview-filename").val(file.name);            
            img.attr('src', e.target.result);
            $preview.attr("data-content",$(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
        }        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });  
});
```

```css
.container{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.image-preview-input {
    position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0px;    
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;    
}
.image-preview-input input[type=file] {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.image-preview-input-title {
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">  
            <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> 
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group image-preview [TO HERE]--> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



   

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">  
            <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/> 
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">  
            <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> 
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                   
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                    </button>
                    <!-- image-preview-input -->
                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/> <!-- rename it -->
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to post your [mcve] in your answer. Links rot. Third-party sites get blocked, sold, and go down.

Comment: Fantastic answer.